# ArcMap can't switch layers order

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, display

I have 5 different layers. I would like to change the order they are drawn. I read that (and I also used to) simply select and drag the layer from in the position I want. Nevertheless, now I am trying to do it again and when I try it seems impossible to me to drop the layer anywhere. My layers come from the same geodatabase, as shown in [image: this image]

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your view in the Table of Contents.

You are currently looking at the "List by Source View"
[image: List Layers by Source]

This view does not let you re-order layers.  In order to do that, you need to change to the "List by Drawing Order" view.
[image: List by drawing order view with note]

You can tell you are in the drawing order view because the layer source path disappears from the Table of Contents listing.
[image: List by drawing order - No file path]

Comment: It works. Thank you, even if it is already few months I am working with this software, it is still quite tricky for me